# Como puedo llamar a una id con el evento OnClick con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

como puedo ejecutar una id con Onclick y con JavaScript
Aqui es donde quiero hacer el boton con OnClick

```html
<div id="content_right" class="content_right animate__animated animate__backInRight">
    <div class="loader" style="display: block;">
        <div class="pag-default">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="title_bans">
        <h1 class="title">
            <span class="icon-stats-dots"></span>
             Betados
        </h1>
        <a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="ActualizarPag()" class="actualizar-button">
            <span class="ic-button icon-spinner11"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="comentarios">
        <p> 
            "Los jugadores que se encuentran en esta lista son jugadores que fueron betados de la comunidad por un servidor o algun administrador por una razon, si fuiste baneado por un administrador debes subir tu <span>'POV DEMO'</span> a cualquier nube y enviar a un <span>'Fundador, Dueño o Socio'</span> luego de que la demo sea analizada segun el veredicto de la demo se aplica el desbaneo, de lo contrario el jugador no tendra derecho a un desbaneo en la comunidad"
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="betados">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="thl thr" width="15%">Fecha </th>
                    <th class="thnone" width="5%"> </th>
                    <th class="thnone title_banlist" width="20%">
                        <span class="icon-user-tie"></span>
                         LISTA DE BANEADOS
                    </th>
                    <th class="thl" width="20%">Razón </th>
                    <th width="10%">Status </th>
                    <th width="15%">Fecha de Expiración</th>
                    <th class="thr" width="5%">Match </th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                while($top = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                {
                    $diasBaneados = floor($top["ban_length"] / 1440);
                    $horasBaneadas = floor($top["ban_length"] / 60);
                    if(($top["bid"] % 2) == 0)
                    {
                        ?>
                        <tr onclick="DisplayBetado(<?php echo $top['bid']?>)" class="tr_2">
                            <td>
                                <?php echo gmdate("d/m/Y - h:i A", ($top["ban_created"] - 14400));?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="avatar">
                                <a target="_blank" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<?php echo getSteam64($top["player_id"]);?>">
                                    <img src="img/default_avatar.jpg" alt>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="name">
                                <?php echo substr($top['player_nick'], 0, 15) ?>
                            </td>
                            <td><?php echo $top["ban_reason"] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $top["player_id"] ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <?php if($top["ban_length"] == 0) 
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    Nunca
                                <?php }
                                else if($top["expired"] == 1)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    Expirado
                                <?php }
                                else if($top["ban_length"] >= 1440)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <?php echo "$diasBaneados" ?> días
                                <?php } 
                                else if($top["ban_length"] >= 60)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <?php echo "$horasBaneadas" ?> hora
                                <?php }
                                else if($top["ban_length"] >= 5)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <?php echo $top["ban_length"] ?> minutos
                                <?php } ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php if($pug_info["pug_hltv"])
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <a><?php echo $pug_info["pug_hash"] ?></a>
                                <?php }
                                else
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <span style="color:#999999;">Sin demo</span>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php }
                    else
                    {
                        $diasBaneados = floor($top["ban_length"] / 1440);
                        $horasBaneadas = floor($top["ban_length"] / 60);
                        ?>
                        <tr onclick="DisplayBetado(<?php echo $top['bid']?>)" class="tr_1">
                            <td>
                                <?php echo gmdate("d/m/Y - h:i A", ($top["ban_created"]-14400));?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="avatar">
                                <a target="_blank" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<?php echo getSteam64($top["player_id"]);?>">
                                    <img src="img/default_avatar.jpg" alt>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="name">
                                <?php echo substr($top['player_nick'], 0, 15) ?>
                            </td>
                            <td><?php echo $top["ban_reason"] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $top["player_id"] ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <?php if($top["ban_length"] == 0) 
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    Nunca
                                <?php }
                                else if($top["expired"] == 1)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    Expirado
                                <?php }
                                else if($top["ban_length"] >= 1440)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <?php echo "$diasBaneados" ?> días
                                <?php } 
                                else if($top["ban_length"] >= 60)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <?php echo "$horasBaneadas" ?> hora
                                <?php }
                                else if($top["ban_length"] >= 5)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <?php echo $top["ban_length"] ?> minutos
                                <?php } ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php if($pug_info["pug_hltv"])
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <a><?php echo $pug_info["pug_hash"] ?></a>
                                <?php }
                                else
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <span style="color:#999999;">Sin demo</span>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php }
                } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php if($total_registros != 0)
        {
            ?>
            <?php include "include/web/paginador.php";?>
        <?php } ?>
        <div id="betado_perfil">
            <?php include "include/web/betado_stats.php";?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
    </script>
</div>
```

específicamente en esta parte

```html
        <a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="ActualizarPag()" class="actualizar-button">
            <span class="ic-button icon-spinner11"></span>
        </a>
```

este es el .js

```js
let style = ["betados", "administradores", "ranking", "pug_history", "demo_history"];
var pag = 0;
var pagin = 0;
function ActualizarPag() {
    $('#content_right').load('include/web/content_right_bans.php?i='+ pag + '&c=1&pagina=' + pagin);
    return false;
}
function PaginadorClick(val) {
    pagin = val;
    $('#content_right').load('includes/right_content.php?i='+ pag + '&c=1&pagina=' + val);
    return false;
}
function DisplayRightContent(val) {
    pag = val;
    $('#titulo').load('includes/right_content.php?i=' + val + '&c=0');
    $('#content_right').load('includes/right_content.php?i=' + val + '&c=1');
    $('#menu').load('includes/right_content.php?i='+ val +'&c=2');
    return false;
}
function DisplayMatchContent(match_id) {
    pag = 3;
    $('#titulo').load('includes/right_content.php?i=' + 3 + '&c=0&m=' + match_id);
    $('#content_right').load('includes/right_content.php?i=' + 3 + '&c=1&m=' + match_id);
    $('#menu').load('includes/right_content.php?i='+ 3 +'&c=2&m=' + match_id);
    return false;
}
$('#titulo').load('includes/right_content.php?i=0&c=0');
$('#content_right').load('includes/right_content.php?i=0&c=1');
$('#menu').load('includes/right_content.php?i=0&c=2');
```

y este el index.html

```html
<?php
    $pag = 0;
    include "include/web/steam.php";
    include "include/web/conexion.php";
    include "include/geoip.inc";
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Caracas");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=1">
    <title id="titulo">Baneados | Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/paginador.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/betado_stats.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hover/hover.css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icomoon/style.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="img/logo.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/right_content/administradores.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/right_content/betados.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/right_content/demo_history.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/right_content/pug_history.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/right_content/ranking.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="style_right"></div>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="animate__animated animate__backInDown">
            <div class="banner">
                <img src="img/banner3.png" alt>
            </div>
            <?php include "include/web/menu.php";?>
            <?php include "include/web/content_left.php";?>
            <?php include "include/web/content_right_bans.php";?>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>
                Copyright © 2022 | 
                <a href="index.php">Test e-Sports</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="js/right_content.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
<script src="js/right/betados.js"></script>
<script src="js/right/administradores.js"></script>
<script src="js/right/ranking.js"></script>
</html>
```

lo que pasa es que al darle al boton para recargar los datos de la pagina pero sin tener que recargar dicha pagina este no hace nada, he echo cambios y nada lo hace funcionar, estoy usando pagina localhost no se si tendra algo que ver para que dicha funcion no funcione como es debido, y si se fijan en el .jd hay mas funciones pero estoy yendo por parte y primero estoy yendo con el boton de poder recargar los datos de la pagina sin tener que recargar la pagina

Este es el error que me sale al darle click al boton
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que te refieres a Javascript, no a Java, y deberías primero revisar bien cómo preguntar, no has mostrado ningún ejemplo de nada que hayas intentado

Comment: Listo, ya modifique la publicacion. Si es JavaScript perdon, lo que intento es crear un boton que lo que hace es recargar los datos de la pagina pero sin recargar dicha pagina

Comment: Y tienes el archivo .js bien cargado en tu html?? Si no nos proporcionas un [mre] vamos a perder muchísimo tiempo intentando *adivinar* qué podría estar pasando... Cuando a lo mejor el error es muy obvio pero no lo vemos porque solo vemos lo que tú quieres enseñarnos, y no todo el código necesario para reproducir el problema. Ojo, TODO el necesario **para reproducir el problema**. No **TODO** tu código... Son dos cosas muy diferentes

Comment: Listo, perdon ya agg lo que faltaba

Comment: Subi una foto donde se muestra el error que me salta al darle click al boton